# Does Mono support visual basic (not .NET)?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, mono, cross-platform, portability

Someone asked me today if it was *possible* to port a visual basic application to Linux or similar platform, I assumed it was .NET so I suggested to use Mono, but noticed that on their vb support page they only talk about vb 8 (.NET)

Does mono support non-.NET vb? In fact I'm not sure what he is using, I think vb6, I'm not sure of the versioning at all though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, VB6 is an entirely different beast from VB.NET. Mono is basically there to run (via JITting, interpreting or AOT-compiling) IL - the Intermediate Language that VB.NET and C# compile down to. (Of course it also provides the libraries and compilers.)

Running VB6 requires an entirely different execution environment, basically.

Comment: As I thought.. I'll just remind him vb6 is so old that he should consider rewriting the application in atleast a newer language that can be ported to another OS. He just wanted to save time from rewriting for many platforms. It seems visual studio as a vb->.net converter, worth mentioning as well.

Comment: @John Migrating VB6 to .Net is usually non-trivial. The [Stackoverflow questions on VB6-migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration?sort=votes&pagesize=50) are a good starting point.

Comment: He decided to actually make his application in PHP in the end, as it was just simple "connect and get some info based on input", web browsers are always platform independent instantly :)

Answer (score 4):

No, but you could take a look at [gambas](http://gambas.sourceforge.net)

> Gambas is a free development
>   environment based on a Basic
>   interpreter with object extensions, a
>   bit like Visual Basic™